# How to use firebase in unity web player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, cloud

I try to use firebase sdk in unity web player scene. I find some example REST API wrapper for editor and android platform.

[SimpleFirebaseCSharp](https://github.com/dkrprasetya/simple-firebase-csharp) works fine on Editor, Android, and iOS. It uses a .dll file for firebase function. How can I use firebase in unity web player?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to connect with Firebase's Real-time Database is through its REST API. In Unity web player, I suggest Unity's [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) with **X-HTTP-Method-Override** should be able to do the work smoothly.  You could see their documentation on https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Anyway, I have updated my Firebase REST API wrapper ([simple-firebase-unity](http://u3d.as/pGA), which is actually the same as the one you shared) and now it should also work fine on unity web player. Please check it out again :D